# C++11 , move constructor requiring to call std::move explicitely

Tags: c++11, constructor, move, rvalue-reference

**Case 1** :I am writing a simple move constructor:

```
ReaderValue::ReaderValue(ReaderValue && other)
{
    moveAlloc(other);
}
```

The `moveAlloc` function prototype in the `ReaderValue` class is:

```
void moveAlloc(ReaderValue && other);
```

I get the error from gcc 4.8:

```
cannot bind 'ReaderValue' lvalue to 'ReaderValue&&'
```

So I need to call explicitely this in order to compile:

```
moveAlloc(std::move(other));
```

**Case 2** : Now ReaderValue has a `std::string stringData` member

I make another constructor:

```
ReaderValue(std::string && otherString)
 : stringData(otherString)
{
}
```

This works, I do not need `std::move` to pass otherString to the stringData constructor

**Question : What is the fundamental reason why I need to explicitely call std::move to pass the rvalue to a function in the first case? The error message says other is a lvalue, whereas it does look like a rvalue reference. Why not in the second case?**

(Please don't reply about the actual implementation, or why do I need to do this, blah blah... That's only a fundamental language question)

Comment: maybe you need to std::forward your `other` rather than move ?

Comment: Is there any difference using forward than move here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ReaderValue::ReaderValue(ReaderValue && other)
{
    //other here is a lvalue(has a name) referring to a rvalue
    //move alloc however takes a rvalue
    moveAlloc(other);
}
```

that is why you have to cast your lvalue to a rvalue explicitely

```
moveAlloc(std::move(other)); //other now is a rvalue
```

please note that all std::move does is effectively a cast to rvalue.

In the second example with the string:

```
 ReaderValue(std::string && otherString)
 : stringData(otherString)
{ }
```

calls

```
std::string(const string& other);
```

effectively copying the string, while:

```
ReaderValue(std::string && otherString)
: stringData(std::move(otherString))
{ }
```

calls:

```
std::string(string&& other);
```

moving your string

Comment: You meant to write `: stringData(std::move(otherString))` in the second-to-last snippet in your post.

Answer (score 1):

Suggest you to read this http://thbecker.net/articles/rvalue_references/section_05.html
it'll will tell you why.

In a short, c++ regards parameter `other` in `ReaderValue`  as a lvalue, but the parameter `other` in `moveAlloc` is a rvalue. So you have to convert `other` in `ReaderValue`  to a rvalue when you call `moveAlloc`.

Comment: But in the second case, will it see `otherString` as a lvalue too, and call the copy constructor for `std::string`?

Comment: Yes,  is there any problem?

Comment: Yes, I want to call the move constructor for efficiency